# How to use the response of one api call as a parameter to another api call? React-query

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query, react-typescript, tanstackreact-query

I have a call to an api that returns some data and displays it in a table. Each row contains an icon that when clicking on it, it must make another call passing it as parameters 2 data from the response of the first call. Depending on the row, the data to be passed as parameters are different.

## First call

```
const {data: eventReconciliationList, refetch, isError, isLoading, isFetching} = useQuery({
    queryKey: [
      "eventReconciliation",
      filters.value.page,
      filters.value.size,
      filters.value.sort,
    ],
    queryFn: () => getEventReconciliationService(
      mapEventReconciliation(
        filters.value
      )
    ),
    enabled: enabled.value

  });

const mapTollingResponseToRows = (rows: TGetEventReconciliation[] | undefined) => {
    return rows?.map((row: TGetEventReconciliation, index: number) => {
const icons =
row.codBillingEvent && (
            <Icons alt="search" className="cursor-pointer" height={18} icon="icon-search" onClick={() => {
              controller.goViewTripEvents();
              console.log(viewEventDetails);
              search();
            }} />
(the response returns more data, but I only want to show this data)
return {
        index,
        codInvoicingEvent: String(row.codInvoicingEvent),
        datOccurrence: row.datOccurrence,
icons: icons,
      };
});
  };
```

## Second call

(this should be taken from the other caller's response)

```
const values: TViewEventDetails = {
  codInvoicingEvent: 202401000000016955n,
  codInvEventType: 3
};

const useGetViewEventDetails = () => {
  const {data: viewEventDetails, refetch} = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["viewEventDetails"],
    queryFn: () => getViewEventDetails(values.codInvoicingEvent, values.codInvEventType),
    enabled: true
  });
```

Comment: if you just need to provide data to the second api call, you already have variable "row" while looping and rendering the rows, just pass it to the event click handler on your row icon.

Comment: @Arslan I don't quite understand what you mean, the parameters for the new call must be passed here queryFn: () => getViewEventDetails(values.codInvoicingEvent, values.codInvEventType),

Comment: so the second call, is also a useQuery hook ? if that is the case the most simplest is to set some state on icon click and use those state parameters as dependencies inside the second hook so whenever you click and set the state, the query re-runs.

Comment: @Arslan yes, the second call is also a useQuery hook

Comment: then i suggest setting some state and using that state as a dependency to your second hook, that would call the second hook with whatever state you set and whenever that changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned in the comments you can solve this by using react state and effect hooks.

**example solution:**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

// Define a state variable to hold parameters for the second API call
const [viewEventDetailsParams, setViewEventDetailsParams] = useState({
  codInvoicingEvent: null,
  codInvEventType: null
});

// Modify the click handler of the icon to update the state with parameters
const handleIconClick = (codInvoicingEvent, codInvEventType) => {
  setViewEventDetailsParams({
    codInvoicingEvent,
    codInvEventType
  });
  // Optionally, you can navigate or perform any other action here
  controller.goViewTripEvents();
};

// Trigger the second API call with the updated parameters
useEffect(() => {
  if (viewEventDetailsParams.codInvoicingEvent && viewEventDetailsParams.codInvEventType) {
    refetch(); // Assuming refetch is a function provided by useQuery to trigger the query again
    // Optionally, you can pass viewEventDetailsParams.codInvoicingEvent and viewEventDetailsParams.codInvEventType to the second API call
    // This should be handled by your useGetViewEventDetails hook
  }
}, [viewEventDetailsParams]);
```